# Some sequential SignalR invokes getting dropped

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

In our application, the client software is using the .NET Client libraries for SignalR.  Two near-identical calls are made, but only the first one executes.

An object makes the following calls:

```
AddSubscription(typeof(ObjA).Name);
AddSubscription(typeof(ObjB).Name);
```

AddSubscription() is implemented on its parent:

```
_subscribedTypes.Add(type);
_realtimeClient.Invoke("Subscribe", type);
```

The client invoke in this case is a wrapper of IHubProxy for the SignalR client that returns the same task as the IHubProxy.Invoke().  The _realtimeClient itself is ultimately a static client instance shared throughout the application.  We've had no issues with invokes or with subscriptions to events sent by the server prior to this.

For whatever reason, only the first AddSubscription goes through.  If I swap them, then whichever is now first will go through.  If I step through, they both execute.

What might be preventing these from both executing in immediate succession?

*Edit: I should add that while the client instance is static, none of its methods or properties are.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wait for the async method Invoke to complete to see if you get an exception:
_realtimeClient.Invoke("Subscribe", type).Wait();

Make sure you subscribed to all events, you might have an Error event

```
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://url/");
        hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;
        hubConnection.Closed += () => Console.WriteLine("hubConnection.Closed");
        hubConnection.ConnectionSlow += () => Console.WriteLine("hubConnection.ConnectionSlow");
        hubConnection.Error += (error) => Console.WriteLine("hubConnection.Error {0}: {1}", error.GetType(), error.Message);
        hubConnection.Reconnected += () => Console.WriteLine("hubConnection.Reconnected");
        hubConnection.Reconnecting += () => Console.WriteLine("hubConnection.Reconnecting");
        hubConnection.StateChanged += (change) => Console.WriteLine("hubConnection.StateChanged {0} => {1}", change.OldState, change.NewState);
```